# Is there anything wrong with taking immediate actions in constructors?

Tags: language-agnostic, oop, constructor

I have classes like this one:

```
class SomeObject
{
    public function __construct($param1, $param2)
    {
       $this->process($param1, $param2);
    }
    ...
}
```

So I can instantly "call" it as some sort of global function just like

```
new SomeObject($arg1, $arg2);
```

which has the benefits of

- staying concise,
- being easy to understand,

but might break unwritten rules of semantics by not waiting till a method is called.

Should I continue to feel bad because of a bad practice, or there's really nothing to worry about?

**Clarification:**

- I do want an instance of the class.
- I do use internal methods of the class only.
- I initialize the object in the constructor, but call the "important" action-taker methods too.
- I am selfish in the light of these sentences.

**Example:**

To give you an idea how I usually use this approach:

```
new Email('to@example.com', 'Subject line', 'Body Text');
```

I avoid to overuse it, of course, but in my opinion, this is really handy.

Comment: Reads more like you want a static function on that object.

Comment: @qor72 I definitely want an instance of that class, but I'm lazy to type variables and call the same method over and over again.

Comment: I don't understand in any way why this is easier than calling `SomeObject->process($param1, $param2)` directly.

Comment: can you give us a brief example of what you are actually trying to do in context?  This is very vague, and a little context could tell us if what you are doing is actually bad or not.

Comment: The "important action taker methods" would be best left out of the constructor, usually, if they dont relate to actual construction of the object.

invisible code can be dangerous and hard to maintain

Comment: @Lerxst Added an example. As you guess it, initializing an `Email` class sends the message without further actions (methods).

Comment: `email = new Email(stuff); email.Send();` why make the life of the people who read your code so unnecessarily hard? Logically, the Email constructor _creates_ an email. Creating an email does not involve sending the email. That's a seperate concept. Therefore, the Email constructor should not send the email.

Comment: @Joren: Verbose and always repeated steps make programming life hard. I cut the obvious. Of course the email is sent after creation. If there is no other use case, why would I want to complicate?

Comment: use cases are only part of the equation.  it doesnt make sense to immediately send the email, significantly reducing the usefulness of the constructor, just to save a single line of code.  It's not part of building the object, and doesnt belong in the constructor.  as Joren said, Creating the email (construction) doesnt involve sending it (no matter what the use case is.  this is from an OO standpoint)

Comment: another issue, what if another user was developing using your code, and attempted to create an email with your constructor.  If I were in that dev's shoes, I would NOT be expecting the constructor to send that email, and I would be pretty flabbergasted if it did :)

Comment: @pestaa: 1) An Email class would also be useful for storing an email for later sending, for representing a _received_ email, and possibly even things like email drafts. 2) The use case now may be immediately sending the email, but that doesn't mean this will always be so. One of the points of OOP is the easy extensibility and reusability of code. Your way of coding breaks that. 3) Your code is nonobvious, even if emails are always immediately sent, since creation and sending are _different concepts_, and people reading your code will see them as such. The principle of least surprise applies.

Comment: Google's "Writing Testable Code" guide has a nice section on this: http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if the code in the constructor is part of creating and initializing the object for use, then I would put it there, but thats me personally, some people may disagree

however, it looks like what you are doing is not intended for building the object/class but doing some other process. this is bad, and should be done in a separate method.

Keep the constructor for construction.

Comment: Added an example above. The thing is, let's say, `dispatch()` in the example does not really belong to the "other processes" category, bot not to object creation either. What's your take?

Comment: @pestaa- everything you said is fine, EXCEPT for sending the email. That is not part of creating and initializing, and definitely belongs in a separate method. What if you want to pass the email object somewhere or modify something before you send it? you can't, unless you have more constructors.  take out the send, and you're good.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bad practice.

Using a constructor as a global function is not at all what it is intended for, and it would easily be confused. It is not easy to understand at all.

If you want a global function, declare one:

```
function myGlobalFunction(){ return $something; }
```

It really isn't that hard...

and even if you aren't using it as a function, you should use the constructor to do just that, construct an object. If you do more than that, you aren't using it for the right purpose, and future contributors will probably get confused quickly.

So, program in a way the makes sense. It really isn't that hard. A few extra keystroke can save you a lot of confusion.

If you need to always take certain actions after making a new instance of a class, try a factory:

```
 class myFactory{
       public static function makeObject(){
           $obj = new Object();
           $obj->init1();
           return $obj;
       }
 }

 $obj = myFactory::makeObject();
```

Comment: I didn't intend to use it as a global function, it was a mere metaphor.

Comment: I sometimes do this to call a "clear()" function to have all reset code at a single place, otherwise you could get inconsistent behaviour.

Comment: -1: I agree with @pestaa. Your answer doesn't really correspond to the question.

Comment: @pestaa Probably a good idea to find out what "metaphor" means before using the word.

Comment: @Jim There is this thing called editing that people on StackOverflow tend to do to improve their answer, while still giving a valid answer as soon as possible.

Comment: @catchme Yes, and this is related to properly building the object for use, so i would put it in the constructor

Comment: Neil, if I said "illustration", would have you been so nice to focus on the question?

Comment: BTW, you can make the factory a part of the actual class, so instead of `new MyClass()` you call `MyClass:createInstance()`

Comment: @Chacha102 The point of my choice was to make code cleaner in terms of ASCII characters, but I feared it can become less clearer in terms of design. I don't want to talk about alternatives.

Comment: @Chacha102: You said 'it really isn't that hard' twice in your post. People come here seeking help, and by writing a question are already admitting that they don't know the proper answer to their problem. Go easy on them... Besides, what is and isn't hard is subjective. :)

Comment: @brunco When I mentioned it 'wasn't that hard', I was referring to the extra typing/thinking. :)

Answer (score 4):

Occam's Razor says *entia non sunt multiplicanda praeter necessitatem*, literally: "entities must not be multiplied beyond necessity". There's nothing wrong with doing work in a constructor[*], but don't require callers to create an object they don't use, just to get the side-effects of its constructor.

[*] Assuming that you're comfortable with the mechanism that your programming language uses to indicate the failure of a constructor. Returning a success/failure code out of a constructor might not be an option, so if you want to avoid an exception in the failure case, then you might be reduced to setting "is usable" flags in the object, which isn't great for usability either.

Comment: +1 for using latin :D

also for the logical, non-technical aspect of this debate

Comment: +1 Absolutely. So in your terms this question is about whether calling the essence of a class in the constructor is a side effect or not. (Error management is not an issue in my situation, but you made valid points others may want to consider.)

Comment: I would say that the "essence of a class" is the objects of that class, and their interface and behaviour defined by the class. If the essence of your class is that it blanks the screen (or whatever), and no user is ever going to care what objects it uses to do so, then it's not "really" a class, it's a routine. Some languages (Java) force you to put every function in a class, leading to the existence of *classes* which are not *types*. I think that requirement is pointless, although I guess it saves the language/bytecode needing to have a syntax/format for free functions.

Comment: ... your Email example looks fine to me, *if* it creates an Email object with the specified details, that can then be used for some or all of the things that you might do to an email (send it, store it, read it). But if on the other hand "Email" in this context is a verb, and the constructor *sends* an email, and the resulting object doesn't represent an email, then I think there's something wrong. In that case, where there are no "email" objects, it's not a class, it's a routine. So write a function called `send_email` (or just `email` if you prefer).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is bad practice for two reasons.

- It is not clear to the caller that other operations above and beyond what is minimally required for initialization are taking place.
- It leads to awkward coding scenarios if this operation throws exception.

Regarding the first point...there is an implicit assumption that constructors only perform enough work to construct an object in a defined and consistent state. Placing extra work in them can lead to confusion if the work is long running or IO bound. Remember, the constructor cannot convey any meaning through its name like methods. One alternative is to create a static factory method with a meaningful name that returns a new instance.

Regarding the second point...if the constructor contains an operation that throws exceptions unpredictably (contrasted with exceptions thrown because of parameter validation for example) then your exception handling code gets awkward. Consider the following example in C#. Notice how the good design has a more elegant feel to it. Nevermind, the fact that the clearly named method is at least an order of magnitude more readable.

```
public class BadDesign : IDisposable
{
  public BadDesign()
  {
    PerformIOBoundOperation();
  }

  private void PerformIOBoundOperation() { }
}

public class GoodDesign : IDisposable
{
  public GoodDesign()
  {

  }

  public void PerformIOBoundOperation() { }
}

public static void Main()
{
  BadDesign bad = null;
  try
  {
    bad = new BadDesign();
  }
  catch
  {
    // 'bad' is left as null reference. There is nothing more we can do.
  }
  finally
  {
    if (bad != null)
    {
      bad.Dispose();
    }
  }

  GoodDesign good = new GoodDesign();
  try
  {
    good.PerformIOBoundOperation();
  }
  catch
  {
    // Do something to 'good' to recover from the error.
  }
  finally
  {
    good.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Things to be concerned with regarding this pattern:

- Breaking Single Responsibility Principle
- Implementing Functional Decomposition Antipattern
- Failing to meet common consumer expectations

**Single Responsibility Principle**

This is a slight variation on the original principle, but applied instead to functions.  If your constructor is doing more than one thing (constructing and processing) you make the maintenance of this method more difficult in the future.  If a caller doesn't want to process during construction, you leave him no option.  If the "processing" one day requires additional steps that shouldn't be in the constructor, you have to refactor everywhere you use this method.

**Functional Decomposition Antipattern**

Without knowing specifics, I'd be concerned that code that does this implements this antipattern.  The objects aren't truly objects, but functional programming units wrapped in object oriented disguise.

**Common consumer expectations**

Would the average caller expect this behavior of the constructor?  There might be places where extra processing during construction can be a short hand programming convenience.  But this should be *explicitly* documented and well understood by the callers.  The overall use of the object should still make sense in this context and it should be natural for the caller to use it in this fashion.

Also understand what you are forcing on your consumer.  If you are doing processing in the constructor, you are forcing the consumer to pay for that processing (in terms of processing time) whether they want it or not.  You eliminate the possibility of doing "lazy" processing or other forms of optimization.

**Acceptable usage?**

Only in places where common use of the class requires initialization that can be optional at construction time.  The File class is a good example:

```
/* This is a common usage of this class */
File f;
f.Open(path);

/* This constructor constructs the object and puts it in the open state in one step 
 * for convenience */
File f(path);
```

But even this is questionable.  Does the file class keep the path to the file internally or is it just used to open a file handle?  If it does store the file path, now Open() and the new constructor have more than one responsibility ( SetPath(p) and Open() ).  In that case, maybe the File(path) convenience constructor shouldn't open the file, but should rather just set the path in the object.

There are lots of considerations based on the objects in question.  Consider writing unit tests for your objects.  They will help you work out a lot of these use case issues.

Answer (score 0):

To my mind, it depends on what the purpose of the function is.

For example, something that I feel would be entirely appropriate to call at the end of a constructor might be something like a `refreshCache()` function.  It's a real public function as other objects may wish to call it, but at the same time you know it's the same logic that you want to apply initially while setting up your object.

In a general sense, I suppose the kind of (public) functions you'd want to call during a constructor are typically idempotent functions that manipulate the local state, so often things like cache population/prefetching things/etc.

If you have an object that does some kind of processing on an input, I would definitely avoid

```
s = new MyObject(a, b)
return s.getResult()
```

in favour of

```
s = new MyObject() // perhaps this is done elsewhere, even once at startup
return s.process(a, b)
```

as arguably the latter is clearer as to what is actually happening (especially if you give `process()` a real name :-)), and lets you reuse a single, lighter-weight object for the calculations, in turn making it easier to pass around.

Of course, if you have quite a complex constructor (this is probably a bad thing in general, but doubtless there are some cases where it makes sense), then it's never a bad thing to separate a block of related functionality out into a *private* function for readability.

Comment: Andrzej, I do not store the object in a variable, not even a second. Therefore I cannot call a second method (beyond the constructor). At least not in PHP as we're left without method chaining.

Your answer is more of a naming convention debate. And I agree!

Answer (score 0):

This is concise, but it is not remotely idiomatic, so it's not easy for others to understand.

In the future, it may not even be easy for you to understand it.

It may not be important to you, but one problem with this is it makes your classes harder to test - see [Flaw: Constructor does Real Work](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/).

Comment: I disagree with "Constructor does Real Work" being _always_ a flaw.  A constructor sometimes _does_ need to do real work -- to set up the environment for the new object.  Taking such initialization out of the ctor makes construction of the object partial or incomplete, requiring the _caller_ to remember to initialize the object properly.  For example, I have a `UIPanel` constructor, which indeed _does_ populate itself with a `backing=new HotSpot(dimensions)`. (for detecting mouse clicks and showing a base color).

Answer (score 0):

Your class is technically fine, and it might simply come down to personal philosophy.

but to others reading this that might get some crazy ideas about constructors, read this:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0618.html

If you're going to start throwing around the "this" reference, you can end up in a lot of trouble, especially in multi-threaded environments. Just an FYI.